# Opening Preview in Safari From Brackets

Tags: javascript, html, adobe-brackets

I'm new to using Brackets. I'm currently using it to write Javascript code and I would like to open my website previews in Safari. Currently when I click the lightening bolt to preview my website opens up in Google Chrome. I prefer to view my code in Safari is there a way to change this? I checked settings but I was not able to find anything that could change the browser that previews my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Brackets v1.14 you can't.

> Live Preview connects Brackets to your browser. It launches a preview
>   of your HTML file in the browser, then updates the preview instantly
>   as you edit your code.
>
> In this early version of Brackets, Live Preview only works with **Google
>   Chrome** and updates live as you edit **CSS or HTML files**. Changes to
>   JavaScript files are automatically reloaded when you save.

[image: Proof that you can't]